# Function of this particular PHP class

Tags: php, function, class, oop, templates

I'm new to PHP "class". I'm looking for a script that can help me create PHP templates, I found this one but I can't seem to understand what is happening here. Can anyone please explain in details. I will be very grateful. Thanks..

```
<?php
class skin {
    var $filename;

public function __construct($filename) {
    $this->filename = $filename;
}

public function mk($filename) {
    $this->filename = $filename;
    return $this->make();
}

public function make() {
    global $CONF;
    $file = sprintf('./'.$CONF['theme_path'].'/'.$CONF['theme_name'].'/html/%s.html', $this->filename);
    $fh_skin = fopen($file, 'r');
    $skin = @fread($fh_skin, filesize($file));
    fclose($fh_skin);

    return $this->parse($skin);
}

private function parse($skin) {
    global $TMPL, $LNG;

    $skin = preg_replace_callback('/{\$lng->(.+?)}/i', create_function('$matches', 'global $LNG; return $LNG[$matches[1]];'), $skin);
    $skin = preg_replace_callback('/{\$([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}/', create_function('$matches', 'global $TMPL; return (isset($TMPL[$matches[1]])?$TMPL[$matches[1]]:"");'), $skin);

    return $skin;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question? I recommend you take a look at this - **[Ask]** - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning of the class `__construct()` assigns the filename to a variable so to be used everywhere in the class (`$filename`).

Then there is a function that parse it `parse()`.

But this function is nested into another function for technical purposes. the private keyword before parse() means it could be used by the class itself.

Hence, the function `make()` is responsible for making use of `parse()`;

A final function `mk()` calls `make()`.

`parse()` parses the template. Means it replaces the actual final parsed variables and data with the template special syntax (which you must refer to in your template file).

`make()` function gets the content of the file and `printf()` in it generates a usable full URL from the given params to it.